# Kurdika - Lojasewicz inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization, machine-learning

i don't understand why a specific function satiesfies the Kurdika -
Lojasewicz inequality. I have the function:

$\sum_{i=1}^{K}\rho^2_{\text{hinge}}(y_i(w^Tx_i+b))+f(w)$

where $w\in\mathbb{R}^n,b,x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $ \rho^2_{\text{hinge}}$ is just the squared hinge loss and the function f is defined as:

$(\forall w=(w_i)_{1\leq i\leq N}\in\mathbb{R}^N) \quad f(w)=\sum^N_{i=1} \varphi(w_i) +||w||^2$

for the function $\varphi$ we have the 2 choices

$(\forall w\in\mathbb{R})\quad \varphi(w)=\lambda\sqrt{w^2+\delta^2}$

and

$(\forall w\in\mathbb{R})\quad \varphi(w)=\lambda(1-\exp{(-\frac{w^2}{2\delta^2})})$

where
$\lambda,\delta>0$.

In the first choice of $\varphi$ we only have algebraic functions, so its pretty clear that it satasifies the Kurdika - Lojasewicz inequality.

But I am not sure how to proof that in the second case. Would really appreciate your help!